# Broadcom BCM4352 not showing all wifi networks

Tags: networking, drivers, dell, broadcom

I have a *2015 Dell XPS 13 (9343)* with Ubuntu 16.04. Wifi is working using *bcmwl-kernel-source 6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8* and everything works fine except that I cannot see all wifi networks around, in particular the one I want to connect to.

Using an old TP-LINK usb dongle I can connect normally.

I think the problem can be the router mixing up the *b/g/n* and *ac/a/n* fequencies.

Strange thing is that while I was using Ubuntu 14.04 everything worked fine.

Any suggestion about how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is a temporary workaround [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/762256/270625)

But it has to be executed after each reboot.